# Reference Parent Element in JMESPath Filter Expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I have the following JMESPath query

```
query="Reservations[].Instances[].{ \
    InstanceId: InstanceId, \
    RootDeviceVolumeId: BlockDeviceMappings[?DeviceName==\`/dev/sda1\`] \
       | [].Ebs.VolumeId | [0], \
    RootDeviceName: RootDeviceName \
}"

aws ec2 describe-instances --query $query
```

which gives output like this

```
+------------+------------------+----------------------+
| InstanceId | RootDeviceName   | RootDeviceVolumeId   |
+------------+------------------+----------------------+
|  i-12345678|  /dev/sda1       |  vol-abcdef12        |
|  i-98765432|  /dev/sda1       |  vol-ef123456        |
|  i-23456789|  /dev/sda1       |  vol-fedcba09        |
|  i-aabbccdd|  /dev/xvda       |  None                |
+------------+------------------+----------------------+
```

I'd like to find a way to reference the `RootDeviceName` from within the `BlockDeviceMappings` filter expression rather than hard-coding the `/dev/sda1` device name, since sometimes it's `/dev/xvda` for instance. However, I can't find a way to reference a parent element in the filter expression.

Another option would be to map the `RootDeviceName` and `InstanceId` onto a projection of all devices and then pipe that to a filter expression, but the syntax doesn't seem to support including parent elements in projections either.

Am I missing something or is this simply a limitation of the JMESPath syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We would need to have some mechanism that allows you to bind scope, which is something that is not currently possible... yet.  I'm very interested in adding this.  For now you'll have to use an alternate tool.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Are there any proposals around changes to this part the spec yet?

Comment: @jamesls is this still the case now in 2018?

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to add custom functions to your JMESPath-using python code, there is a dirty and ugly way that does something like it. It does violate the "functions should have no side effects" rule. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/martinvirtel/366235401cf7fbec503d53eb44109f25

The fetchstore.py file in the gist adds a fetch and a store function to JMESPath. See the test or the example below for how it works. Here is guidance on how to add functions to your JMESPath-using Python project: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jmespath#custom-functions.

Input:

```
 { "name" : "parent name",
    "data" : [
        { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 },
        { "x" : 3, "y" : 2 }
        ]
    }
```

JMESPath Expression:

```
{ 
  name: store(name,'parent_name_attribute'), 
  data: data[][ fetch('parent_name_attribute'),x, y] 
}
```

Result:

```
{
 "name": "parent name",
 "data": [
           [ "parent name", 1, 2 ],
           [ "parent name", 3, 2 ]
         ]
}
```