# Gathering the values from the keys in a list with JMESPath

Tags: jmespath

Given `{"a": "foo", "b": "bar", "c": "baz"}` and `["b", "c"]`, how to get `["bar", "baz"]`?

I tried `map(*.@, ["b", "c"])` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is literally your list of field.

The query:

```
["b", "c"]
```

<sup>note: which could also be expressed `[b, c]`</sup>

Would give you:

```json
[
  "bar",
  "baz"
]
```

Comment: Is it doable when both the input list and the dictionary are from the object? Say, I have `{"data": {"a": "foo", "b": "bar", "c": "baz"}, "query": {"inner_query": ["b", "c"]}}`. Can I do something like `data.(query.inner_query)`, if the expression makes sense to you?

Comment: In this case, `data.["a", "b"]` will still work, but indeed, you cannot achieve it with another property, since this would require you to do something like `data.[parent.query.inner_query]`, and there is a long standing issue of the functionality to access the parent node missing in JMESPath. See this answer from the main maintainer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/28681315/2123530