Using the length function in a query
I have a dynamically changing JSON array, of unknown size and I need to reference the array length using JMESPath query.
For example
{
  "locations": [
    {"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
    {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}
  ]
}

If I use a query like length(locations), I get the desired result, 4.
And if I use locations[0], I get desired result:
{ 
  "name": "Seattle", 
  "state": "WA" 
}

But, lets say I want to combine both the queries like locations[length(locations)] which should translate to locations[4], this does not work at all. I tried many combinations to get the array length but this is not working.
Can anyone help me here?

If you want to target the last element, you can also use negative indexes:
locations[-1]


A negative number is a valid index. A negative number indicates that indexing is relative to the end of the list

Reference: Index Expressions
Would yield:
{
  "name": "Olympia",
  "state": "WA"
}


I need the length of the array to be passed inside locations and that changes dynamically.

That would not be possible then, because you cannot target the parent node of an element, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673747/reference-parent-element-in-jmespath-filter-expression/28681315#28681315
